# Hiding Unhiding Div Properly using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I Have a div which I display on button click which works fine but on the second button click this is not invoked what's wrong here

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('onclick', myFunction());
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Toggle</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
  <div class="" role="status">
    <h4 class="text-info">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code [works though](https://jsfiddle.net/0j6sn7ov/)

Comment: @Lapskaus yeah it works for the first attempt but second step it stays hidden

Comment: Please click on the link I posted and try it out. The code you provided here works. If there is still a problem in your local version, then you have something else messing with it. We can only review what you provide.

Comment: ohj thanks just tried on second press the loading msg goes away i want the loading message to display everytime button is click untill page is refreshed

Comment: You haven't shown any code which calls `myFunction()`.  Edit your question, show us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet there are some little mistakes:

1. The html for the button lacks of its own **id** that you are using in the js to get the element and to add the event listener to it;
2. The javascript line you use to add the event uses **onclick** event, this doesn't work because with **addEventListener**, you have to use just the event without the **on** part that is needed if you use the inline version of the event, into the html. So basically will be used just **click**, not **onclick**;
3. Adding the event listener don't use the **( )** part of the function that you are adding, that basically makes it execute immediately at the moment the event listener is added to the html element: use just its name so just **myFunction**;
4. Also because we are adding the event listener by js we don't need to use the onclick='myFunction()' part into the html: we use one or the other no need to use both. Also the **addEventListener** way is usually the preferred way to go instead the inline version onclick='myFunction()'. In fact, the **addEventListener** way, keeps the html code cleaner and allows to add multiple events of the same type. But with the onclick='myFunction()' way you can only add one event inline.
5. One more suggestion would be to use a separate css instead of inline style.

Now let's see the corrections in action:

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  let divElStyle = document.getElementById("myDIV").style;
  if (divElStyle.display === "none") {
    divElStyle.display = "block";
  } else {
    divElStyle.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Toggle</button>
<div id="myDIV" class="" role="status" style="display:none;" >
  <h4 class="text-info">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. you do not need an ID to add the event listener. 4. You can add multiple methods inline inside the `onClick`-attribute as usal by seperating them with a `;`.

Comment: @Lapskaus, 1) I agree, but since in the original question the user got the element by the js  code **document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('onclick', myFunction());**, it was necessary to make it coehrent with the related html which was lacking  of the necessary id. 4) I agree too, but as you know today the preferred way is usually to add events with **addEventListner** to keep html more clean Nevertheless your way would work as well..